# Query time for a specific entity is 10000 times higher

Tags: sql, postgresql

We run into a problem: select for a filter by a certain id takes a very long time. For all id about 5ms, for this - 10 seconds.
This is explain. Left - normal, right - long. This is absolutely the same sql query, where the difference is only in one digit 'where id = ...'
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDBKj.png)
It is striking that a filter is used on the right, but for some reason it is not on the left, as well as some huge number of 'rows removed'. Such a number can only be obtained by multiplying the number of rows in the joined tables. Once again I repeat that the sql query is absolutely the same except for the entity id, the number of retrieved data for entities is comparable.
One of the tables also uses btre index. The only thing that this id has is special - it comes after the numbering break, 22,23,24,30 for example. But I was not able to reproduce the problem on this principle.
Unfortunately, I cannot show the code, but I hope that this information will be enough to advise something.

upd:
I found the reason. Postgres for some reason expects that one of the tables will return only 1 structure, when as a real return in 10k+ and therefore chooses the wrong algorithm. For other entity ids, it "thinks" correctly and chooses higher algorithms. Can you find how posgres counts plan lines? What could be the problem?

[image: IMG HERE]

Comment: Please show the actual query, the `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` statements and, most importantly, the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for your query. Otherwise, no meaningful answer can be given.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe 
Hello. Unfortunately, I cannot post this information, but I have clarified the problem and edited the post. Please take a look, maybe you have come across something similar?

Comment: That's still not enough information. We'd have to know the structure of the execution plan - you could obfuscate the actual values and column names, if you want.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm sure this won't help. Removing the index did not help. I tried backing up the schema locally and everything works fine on it. There is some problem with the optimizer on our database server. It seems to me that I could be prompted on the basis of this. What settings might cause the optimizer to work incorrectly

Comment: Did you set `make_postgresql_fast = on`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your problem is data histogram. We cannot support you because you cannot provide example code. Briefly, one of your table has a data whose id columns has heterogenous data in it. For example; your table has 1 billion records and in that table each id has 500 records. Yet, some of the id' s (virtually, let say) 20 or 200 millions records. So, if you search for these highly non-selective rows the database optimizer will not help you.

Check your data histogram!